# How to calculate the size of a control without rendering it

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I wanna create a view not in xaml but in c# with vertical and horizontal options set and get its size without rendering it or adding it to a content page. I know that I can't calculate the size of a view unless we add it to a layout but that also doesn't work because It wasn't rendered.

In conclusion, Xamarin doesn't set the bounds of a view unless It's rendered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can MeasuredHeight property which can help you in your scenario.

```
var textView = new TextView(this);
textView.Text = "Hello";
textView.Measure(0, 0);
int height =  textView.MeasuredHeight;
int width =  textView.MeasuredWidth;
```